# Finding the the Volume using integration/derivatives.

Tags: integration, derivatives

The region bounded by $0\leq y \le e^{2x}$ , $-1\leq x\leq0$ is rotated around the
$x$-axis. Find the volume?

Would someone give me a hand with this question?. Ive gotten great support from this website so far. I Don't have the greatest maths help so I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The volume of a solid of revolution rotated around the $x$-axis is
$$
V = \pi \int_a^b (f(x))^2\,dx\,.
$$
What do you have to plug in for $f$, $a$, $b$?

Comment: -1 for a, 0 for b, and e for f ?

Comment: @ciaranfitz27 Yes, this is almost right. It should be $f(x)=e^{2x}$.

Comment: brilliant just got an answer of 0.7710130943 thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @ciaranfitz27 You’re welcome!